# Double backslashes no longer working in TeX

Tags: bug, status-completed, mathjax

I was pretty sure the admins had fixed things so that two backslashes worked to insert a new line in TeX, but it no longer seems to work. Or rather, it works in the preview page, but not in the final output.

Two backslashes: `\begin{bmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{bmatrix}` produces $$\begin{bmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{bmatrix}$$

Three backslashes: `\begin{bmatrix}a&b\\\c&d\end{bmatrix}` produces $$\begin{bmatrix}a&b\\\c&d\end{bmatrix}$$

Click "edit" to see the desired behaviour.

Comment: It seems that some commands no longer do the right escapes; the triple-backslash has always been necessary in align environments, so far as I can tell, and seems to be required every so often; lately, I've been seeing a disconnect again between the previewer and the renderer on `\{` and `\}` on in-line equations as well.

Comment: @Arturo: [Here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/18067/how-to-justify-step-in-finding-integral-of-erf-error-function-aka-normal-c-d-f/18073#18073) is an answer I wrote recently using double backslashes in an align environment. Strangely enough, it still works.

Comment: Don't know; I keep using double backslash in `align*`s. Maybe it's the stars.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be fixed now -- sorry about that, deployment error.

Comment: Has the fix been deployed, and/or will it only affect newer posts? Because the example in the question is still the same.

Comment: @rahul you will have to do a no-op edit, adding a space, for the write to occur